# Differentiation under double integrals..step by step

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am sorry to be asking a question that has been asked in slightly different forms previously, however I am having problems with the derivation when it comes to double integrals where the outer integral bounds rely on the ones of the inner. I am ending up with a term that I know should not be there. Can someone please provide a step by step derivation instead of a direct result for $\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}F(\beta)$? I will be grateful.

$$F(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\beta}\int_{-x-\beta}^{\infty}f(x,y)dydx$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Leibniz's rule:
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{a\left(\theta\right)}^{b\left(\theta\right)}h\left(x,\theta\right)dx=\int_{a\left(\theta\right)}^{b\left(\theta\right)}h_{\theta}\left(x,\theta\right)dx+h\left(b\left(\theta\right),\theta\right)b^{\prime}\left(\theta\right)-h\left(a\left(\theta\right),\theta\right)a^{\prime}\left(\theta\right).
$$

To make things easier, let
$$
F^{k}\left(\beta\right)\equiv\int_{-k}^{\beta}g^k\left(x,\beta\right)dx
$$
where
$$
g^{k}\left(x,\beta\right)\equiv\int_{-x-\beta}^{k}f\left(x,y\right)dy.
$$
Then apply Leibniz's rule to compute $\partial g^{k}/\partial\beta$
and $\partial F^{k}/\partial\beta$. Plug your expression for the
former into the latter to get an expression for $\partial F^{k}/\partial\beta$
involving $f$. Then, take the limit $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Just a small mistake: In your definition of $F^k$ you want $g^k$ instead of $g$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I know I have to apply Leibniz (thus the title of the q). However I am having problems with the derivation, while fitting the inner inside the outer, that is why I was asking for a step by step derivation. I would appreciate it if you would have time to do it. If not, thanks anyways, I will have another look.